# How to define a method called send in a Rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to define a method `send` in my controller:

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController

  def send
  end

end
```

However, I am getting an error `wrong number of arguments (2 for 0)` when I do this.

So I assume that `send` is a reserved word in Rails?

What could be a possible workaround for defining a `send` method in my controller anyway.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: `send` is a built-in method in ruby. Choose another name. `send_invoice`, for example. Or `create`, if you want to be RESTful.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev +1 http://teachmetocode.com/articles/ruby-on-rails-accessing-controller-methods-from-your-view/

Comment: What exactly is the stacktrace for the error?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot call a method 'send' in ruby. Send is an Object method

send(*args) public

> Invokes the method identified by symbol, passing it
>   any arguments specified. You can use **send** if the name send clashes
>   with an existing method in obj.

[Send method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-send)

Comment: It is not a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't have a `send` method in a controller is that [`send`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send) is already a method on the ruby Object class.

However, coming at the question from a slightly different angle, the main reason I can see to have a specific name for a method in this case is to get that name in the routing so that you can have, e.g.: `http://localhost:3000/invoices/send` or for a RESTful resource `/invoices/123/send`.

In which case you could call the method whatever you like and add a route named `send` to point at your method.

So, in your controller:

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController

  def send_invoice
    ...
  end

end
```

Then in `config/routes.rb`:

```
get 'invoices/send', to: 'invoices#send_invoice'
```

Or for an invoices resource:

```
resources :invoices do
  member :send, to: :send_invoice
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider calling it `post` or `deliver` instead